# Why Undefined is returned after function call

Tags: javascript, undefined, hoisting

I was just playing around hoisting concept in Javascript. I wrote following code while playing around, and I could see an unexpected output 'undefined' at the end.Where is that coming from?

```
  b();
    console.log(a);

    function b(){
        a=10;
        console.log(a*10);
    }

    var a=6;
    console.log(b());
```

Output:

100

10

100

undefined

Comment: Because the function isn’t returning anything.

Comment: The function `b()` does not have a `return` statement, so the return value is `undefined`.

Comment: I suggest stepping through the code line-by-line using the debugger built into your browser. That's the best way to see exactly what's happening in that code (or indeed, in just about any code).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't set a return value for your function, so it is returning the default `undefined`. If you want the function to return the value you calculated, I suggest doing this:

```
function b(){
    a=10;
    calculatedValue = a*10;
    console.log(calculatedValue);
    return calculatedValue;
}
```

It also might be useful to pass a as a parameter of the function:

```
function b(a){
    calculatedValue = a*10;
    console.log(calculatedValue);
    return calculatedValue;
}

var a=6;
console.log(b(a));
```

Answer (score 1):

`undefined` is the default value returned by a function that has no `return` statement (and which is not invoked with the `new` operator).